# Why does this transaction produce a deadlock?

Tags: mariadb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

My application runs on Maria DB using a master-master Galera replication setup.

The application can handle deadlocks, but I've been working to minimize those that occur as they fill up my log files. There remains one transaction that gets regular deadlocks and I don't know how to avoid it.

The process deletes a record from one table, does a couple of operations on other tables and then finally inserts a record into the original table. 
The transaction looks broadly like this:

```
1. DELETE FROM table_a WHERE `id` = 'Foo'
2. REPLACE INTO table_b ( ... )
3. UPDATE table_c SET ....
4. INSERT INTO table_a (id,...) VALUES ('Bar',...)
```

The final insert regularly gets a deadlock although retrying the transaction fixes it. What is it about this pattern that causes a deadlock? What can I do to reduce the occurrence?

Comment: Pls check out the information provided by mariadb in the innodb status monitor on the deadlock. It tells you which statements of which transactions cause the deadlock and the locks set by those statements.

Comment: I've enabled  innodb_status_output  and innodb_status_output_locks although the file configured in log_error doesn't exist. I will see what happens when the next deadlock occurs

Comment: Does `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` say that `INSERT` is conflicting with `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0):

Question:  Is the 'deadlock' in the node you are writing to?  Or does the deadlock not occur until `COMMIT`; that is, when trying to reconcile across the cluster?

If on the writing node...

As soon as possible in the transaction, do

```
SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE ... FOR UPDATE;
```

to signal what row(s) you will be inserting in step 4.

Also, consider changing `REPLACE` to an equivalent `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..`.  I don't know if it will directly help with the deadlock, but at least it is (probably) more efficient.

If on the cluster...

Are you touching lots of different rows?  Are you using roundrobin for picking which node to write to?

In any case, speeding up the transaction will help.  Is there anything that can be pulled out of the transaction.  Some thoughts there:

- Normalization can generally be done in its own transaction.
- If you have an "if" in the transaction, it might be worth it to do a tentative test beforehand.  (But you probably need to keep the "if" in the transaction.)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will try logging the  `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` from the application.

As for node selection. It's master-master. Every application sever reads and writes to its own paired database node.

I will take your suggestion regarding the ON DUPLICATE KEY. Thanks for that idea. I want the efficiency, and I'll keep an eye to see if it reduces the deadlocks.

Comment: I hope you are writing to only one of the pair of Masters.

Comment: Galera cluster allows writing to any node.

Comment: Galera - OK.  I was mislead by "master-master".

Comment: Ah yeh. It calls itself multi-master :) Anyway, I'm using ON DUPLICATE... instead of the replace and will see what happens.

Comment: btw, I added Galera as a tag but someone removed it for some reason.

Comment: In answer to an earlier question, I am seeing deadlocks at commit stage. Should I retry the whole transaction in these cases or just try the commit again?

Comment: @Tim - The whole transaction.  `COMMIT` is when the engine checks with the other nodes, and one of them said "this transaction cannot be committed on my node".  The solution is to start over -- this time (hopefully) getting past whatever was stopping the commit.